# How to check if an argument has both filename and a path or just the filename

Tags: perl

User input can be just a filename / filename with a path of where the file 
exists. These are the only 2 options to users.

```
use File::Basename qw(dirname basename);

my $input = <STDIN>;
my $file = basename($input);
my $path = dirname($input);
```

Whenever user gives just the file name, i am getting path as .(DOT - current directory). The file doesn't exist in that path. For me if the user doesn't provide the path it means i pick it from a specific directory.

I am currently using a crude logic of checking the length of $path to see if a path is given or not.

Is there any other way which i can use which tells if path is mentioned or not. Any inputs are really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check if there's a `/` in the `$input`.

```
use File::Basename qw(dirname basename);

my $input = <STDIN>;
my ($file, $path);

if ($input =~ m{/}) {
    $file = basename($input);
    $path = dirname($input);
} else {
    $path = '/foo/bar/';
    $file = $input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file exists (and is a file) as sent in by the user. If not, prepend the file with your custom directory:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename qw(dirname basename);

my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;

my $file = basename($input);
my $path = dirname($input);

my $custom_dir = '/path/to';

if (! -f $input){
    print "$custom_dir/$file\n";
}
else {
    print "$input\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

```
if ( -f $input ) { 
   #it's a file that exists, so the path is probably right
}
```

Alternatively, you can just test if `$path eq '.'` instead?

Comment: i tried the if ($path eq '.') syntax and i get below error